# How to compile GTK2 on Linux machine without administrator privileges?

Tags: gvim, gtk, suse, autotools

I'm working on a "SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)" machine, which has GVim version 6.4.6, which is quite old, and not supported by some plugins.

This is a corporate machine, and no one will do any administrative changes just because I want to have an alignment plugin...

I've downloaded and successfully compiled version 7.3, with "configure --prefix=/my/local/dir" command.

However, it doesn't recognize GTK2, and keep using the ugly Motif GUI.
It seems that I have too old GTK installed:
"checking for GTK - version >= 2.2.0... no"

I've tried to manually install the GTK2 dev package into local path, but it failed.
Any ideas how can I continue?..

Thanks...

## EDIT

"It failed" - means that I installed glib2, but pango didn't see it. Then I tried jhbuilder, but it just gave strange errors that Googling didn't gave solution...

Answer (score 1):

"but it failed" does not provide enough information about what went wrong, but I have a few hunches. What specific command line options are you trying to use? What error message do you receive?

A few tips for building stuff locally:

- You might need other updated dependencies such as GLib.
- For Autoconf-based programs (that is, usually, given away by the fact that a `./configure` script exists), you need to specify `--prefix=/some/writable/dir` **as well as** set the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to point [`pkg-config`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config) at the right place.
- You basically need to create a directory, e.g. `/home/you/usr` which is *your local equivalent to* `/usr`, and convince the build scripts of libraries such as `GLib` and `GTK` to use `/home/you/usr` for **everything** -- when in doubt, run the config script with `strace -Ff -eopen` if you can, and see what files it accesses in `/usr` and then google a way to get it to look in `/home/you/usr` instead.
- You may also have to override the default install path for libraries by passing `--libdir=/home/you/usr/lib` to the configure script.
- The linkage -- that is, which directories are taken to be linked against for each link step -- is handled by correctly installing the `.pc` files for the dependency libraries into `/home/you/usr/lib/pkg-config`. So, in other words, the automatically-generated `.pc` files that get installed into `/home/you/usr/lib/pkg-config` when you run `make install` on an autotooled program will, assuming you set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` correctly, tell the compiler to link against `/home/you/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so` and *not* `/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so` (for example).

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks to allquixotic, I have now a beautiful local GVim7.3 :)

To the benefit of future readers, I'll summarize it up. (hoping that I didn't forget anything...):

Before running:

```
setenv CPPFLAGS "-I/local/path/usr/include"
setenv LDFLAGS "-L/local/path/usr/lib"
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/local/path/usr/lib"
setenv PKG_CONFIG_PATH "/local/path/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
```

In each component, compile with the following commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/local/path/usr
make
make install
```

Now, these are the versions I've used (note that the order is important):

```
glib-2.10.3
atk-1.9.1
freetype-2.2.1
fontconfig-2.3.97
cairo1.0.4
pixman0.9
pango-1.12.4
gtk+-2.8.20
```

After that, I could compile Vim7.3 with the following configuration:

```
   configure --prefix=/local/path/usr --with-features=big --enable-gui=gtk2 | tee config.log
```

And verify that gtk is found.